# I am getting "message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity" in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Android Studio. I started building an app. This is the code of my xml file. I can't figure out the problem! This is the exact error code that I am getting."ParseError at [row,col]:[60,1]
Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#121212"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="844dp"
        android:layout_height="1090dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.988"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/up_notch_adobespark" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/more_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.997"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.004"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/help_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_tamma"
        android:text="Hi Josh."
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.065"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.158" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like broot explained … XML syntax is similar to HTML it has an opening and closing tag, so you need to close every single tag you open in which your case is the constraint layout . just add this line to the end of your xml file

`</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

---

another advice would be very useful is to avoid using `horizontal and vertical bias`, I believe that padding(s) and margins(s) are more than enough to help you design the layout you want

and try also using for width and height  `wrap_content or match parent` for detailed and correct measurement for the most phones that will be used.  because if you changed the amuleter  you are using you will notice that the measurement will be diffrient so as a best practice is to use  `wrap_content` or `match parent`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer as well as all the tips you gave. It is lot to me. 

Answer (score 1):

Error message is pretty self-explanatory. You opened `ConstraintLayout` tag at the beginning of the document, but you never closed it. You need to add the following at the end:

```xml
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It solves my problem. 